# Mockery Doctrine / Repository with more than one method

Tags: doctrine-orm, phpunit, mockery

I am using the mockery to test a method that make a lot of doctrine repository invocations with different repositories.
This is the method that i set up all my repository mocks:

```
public function testService()
{
    $mockDoctrine = $this->getMockDoctrine();
    $mockDoctrine->shouldReceive('getRepository')->once()
        ->andReturn($this->getRepositoryAMock());

    $mockDoctrine->shouldReceive('getRepository')->once()
        ->andReturn($this->getRepositoryBMock());

    $mockDoctrine->shouldReceive('getRepository')->once()
        ->andReturn($this->getRepositoryCMock());

    //here is where i hit my test
    $products = $this->service->fire(1, 1);

    $this->assertInstanceOf('Illuminate\Support\Collection', $products);
    foreach ($products as $v) {
        $this->assertInstanceOf('Illuminate\Support\Collection', $v);
    }
}
```

This is the method that i mock the Doctrine:

```
public function getMockDoctrine()
{
    $mockDoctrine = \App::make('Doctrine');
    $mockDoctrine->shouldReceive('persist')
        ->andReturn(true);
    $mockDoctrine->shouldReceive('flush')
        ->andReturn(true);

    return $mockDoctrine;
}
```

These are my repositories mock

```
public function getRepositoryAMock()
{
    $repository = \Mockery::mock('MyARepository');
    $repository->shouldReceive('findBy')
        ->with(['paramA' => 1, 'paramB' => 1])
        ->andReturn($this->getMockA());

    return $repository;
}

public function getRepositoryBMock()
{
    $repository = \Mockery::mock('MyBRepository');
    $repository->shouldReceive('findById')
        ->with(1)
        ->andReturn($this->getMockA());

    return $repository;
}

public function getRepositoryCMock()
{
    $repository = \Mockery::mock('MyCRepository');
    $repository->shouldReceive('findOneBy')
        ->with(['paramA' => 1, 'paramB' => 1])
        ->andReturn($this->getMockA());

    return $repository;
}
```

This is where in fact i set the return of my mock

```
public function getMockA()
{
    $obj = new MyClass();
    $reflection = new \ReflectionClass($obj);
    $id = $reflection->getProperty('id');
    $id->setAccessible(true);
    $id->setValue($obj, 1);
    $obj
        ->setLogin('foo')
        ->setPassword('bar')
        ->setCode(1);

    return $obj;
}
```

And then i receive an error like this:

1) MyClassTest::testService
BadMethodCallException: Method Mockery_2_ClassBRepository::findOneBy() does not exist on this mock object

Assuming that i have 3 methods with repositories being called in testService() method, the method that mockery is not finding is in the third one, but mockery thinks it is in the second, so obviously he won't find, because in the second one, does not exist the "findOneBy()" doctrine method just in the third.

How can i solve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use mockery's with().
For example:

```
$mockDoctrine
    ->shouldReceive('getRepository')
    ->with('MyAReposiotry')->once()
    ->andReturn($this->getRepositoryAMock());
```

And like that for every repository (with different value in with).

But I would rather inject repositories in that service instead of getting it from entity manager inside service. It is way better for testing. Take a look at [this blog post](http://php-and-symfony.matthiasnoback.nl/2014/05/inject-a-repository-instead-of-an-entity-manager/).

Comment: Other error came up with the "with": Mockery\Exception\NoMatchingExpectationException: No matching handler found for Mockery_1_. Either the method was unexpected or its arguments matched no expected argument list for this method

Comment: Are you sure that you put right value in with()? You should put the same value you are using to get that entity in service.

Comment: Yep, it's the same, should i change something in the "**getRepositoryAMock**" method ?

Comment: Well actually no (if MyARepository is real class with right namespace). But the thing is that I am getting my repositories with entity name, not repository name (->getRepository('Bundle:SomeEntity') instead ->getRepository('SomeRepository')). That's why asked you if  you are sure if you are getting repositories like that. Maybe you can pastebin the service itself.

Comment: Oh Yes, it worked! I am using the entity too to get the repository, i changed that in the code and it works now! Thanks a lot Mr Ivan. =)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Mr Ivan,

Now my method is working.

In my real class, i was getting the repository with the entity class,
like:

```
 Doctrine::getRepository('MyEntityClassA')
        ->findBy(['paramA' => 1, 'paramB' => 1]);
```

so i changed my test method to use the "with" passing the entity class:

```
public function testService()
{
    $mockDoctrine = $this->getMockDoctrine();
    $mockDoctrine->shouldReceive('getRepository')
        ->with('MyEntityClassA')->once()
        ->andReturn($this->getRepositoryAMock());

    $mockDoctrine->shouldReceive('getRepository')->once()
        ->with('MyEntityClassB')->once()
        ->andReturn($this->getRepositoryBMock());

    $mockDoctrine->shouldReceive('getRepository')->once()
        ->with('MyEntityClassC')->once()
        ->andReturn($this->getRepositoryCMock());

    //here is where i hit my test
    $products = $this->service->fire(1, 1);

    $this->assertInstanceOf('Illuminate\Support\Collection', $products);
    foreach ($products as $v) {
        $this->assertInstanceOf('Illuminate\Support\Collection', $v);
    }
}
```